# Smart file component(html5smartfile) not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I have been working on developing a custom extjs console to enable author drop an asset using **html5smartfile** component. But somehow, the html5smartfile component is not working the way it should. The Area where an author can drop an asset is not displaying. The same is working fine if I am creating a CQ5 dialog. But in my case where i have created a window it's not working.

I have declared my smartfile component like this:

```
var assetLinkDropField = {
xtype: 'html5smartfile',
fieldLabel: 'Asset Link',
ddAccept: 'video/.*',
ddGroups: 'media',
fileReferenceParameter: './linkUrl',
name: './linkUrl',
allowUpload: false,
allowFileNameEditing: false,
allowFileReference: true,
transferFileName: false
};
```

But this is rendering like this:

[image]

After a lot of work, I found out that the CQ5 dialog updates the view for the component but in case of my window, I have to update it myself. Thus, with a slight manipulation, i just succeeded in displaying the drag area by tweaking the declaration like this:

```
var assetLinkDropField = {
xtype: 'html5smartfile',
fieldLabel: 'Asset Link',
ddAccept: 'video/.*',
ddGroups: 'media',
fileReferenceParameter: './linkUrl',
name: './linkUrl',
allowUpload: false,
allowFileNameEditing: false,
allowFileReference: true,
transferFileName: false,
listeners: {
    afterlayout: function () {
        this.updateView();
    }
}
}
```

So now the panel looks like:

[image]

But still the Drag and Drop is not working. My Window declaration is like this:

```
win = new CQ.Ext.Window({
                height          : 750,
                width           : 700,
                layout          : 'anchor',
                // animateTarget   : btn.el,
                closeAction     : 'close', // Prevent destruction on Close
                id              : 'manageLinkWindow',
                title           : '<b>Multi Link Widget Dialog</b>',
                frame           : true,
                draggable       : false,
                modal           : false, //Mask entire page
                constrain       : true,
                buttonAlign     : 'center',
                items : [assetLinkDropField]
              });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use
ddAccept: 'video/.*',
This allows only videos from the content finder to be dragged and dropped. It should be "image/".

Verify your other extjs properties / configs for html5smartfile if the above doesn't resolves your problem.

Comment: html5smartimage was added in CQ5.5 to replace the previously available smartimage widget. [API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartImage)

Comment: @rakhi4110 its html5smartfile and not html5smartimage, I do know this in the api docs..

Comment: html5smartfile for file uploads. The html5smartimage extends from html5smartfile and provides additional features. I guess u missed to check the link which i provided. Here once again for your reference http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartImage

Comment: Right pardon me. I missed it.